# A Simple Application of Mean Value Theorem?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, definite-integrals

If $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous, $a>0$ and $\int_{-a}^a f(x)dx=0$, prove that there exists some $\xi\in (0,a)$ such that
$$\int_{-\xi}^{\xi}f(x)dx=f(\xi)+f(-\xi)$$

A natural idea is to consider the function $g:[0,a]\to \mathbb{R}$, where
$$g(y)=\int_0^y \left\{\int_{-x}^x f(t)dt-\left[f(x)+f(-x)\right]\right\}dx$$
It is easy to see that $g$ is differentiable on $(0,a)$ and that $g(0)=0$. Furthermore, note that
$$\int_0^y f(-x)dx=-\int_0^{-y}f(z)dz=\int_{-y}^0 f(z)dz$$
Therefore, we know that
$$g(a)=\int_0^a \int_{-x}^x f(t)dtdx-\int_{-a}^a f(x)dx=\int_0^a \int_{-x}^x f(t)dtdx$$
If $\int_0^a \int_{-x}^x f(t)dtdx=0$, then by the mean value theorem, there exists some $\xi$ such that
$g'(\xi)=0$, i.e. that
$$\int_{-\xi}^{\xi}f(x)dx=f(\xi)+f(-\xi)$$
However, in general $\int_0^a \int_{-x}^x f(t)dtdx$ need not be $0$.

Let $h(x)=\int_{-x}^x f(t)dt$. Then $h'(x)=f(x)-(-1)f(-x)=f(x)+f(-x)$. Also, $h(0)=h(a)=0$. So there exists some $w\in (0,a)$ such that
$$f(w)+f(-w)=h'(w)=0$$
But this only proves that $\int_{-a}^a f(x)dx=f(w)+f(-w)$ though. I'm not sure how to proceed.

What can we do when $\int_0^a \int_{-x}^x f(t)dtdx\neq 0$? Or is there some clever trick that I didn't notice? Any hint will be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: I don't know if this helps, but switching the order of integration gives us
$$
\int_0^a \int_{-x}^x f(t)\,dt\,dx = \int_{-a}^a \int_{|t|}^a f(t)\,dx\,dt = 
\int_{-a}^a (a - |t|)f(t)\,dt
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you note, it suffices to show that for a differentiable function $h(\xi)$ with $h(0) = h(a) = 0$, there exists a $\xi \in (0,a)$ such that $h(\xi) = h'(\xi)$.

To that end, note that
$$
h(\xi) - h'(\xi) = 0 \iff h'(\xi)e^{-\xi} - h(\xi)e^{-\xi} = 0.
$$
If we define the new function $H(x) = e^{-x}h(x)$, it suffices to show that, given $H(0) = H(a) = 0$, there is a $\xi$ with $H'(\xi) = 0$. However, this is precisely the content of Rolle's theorem.

Answer (score 1):

Define the function $g$ as
$$g(x)=\int_{-x}^x f(t)dt$$
So that your problem is equivalent to proving the existence of some $\xi\in (0,a)$ such that
$$g(\xi)=g’(\xi)$$
knowing that $g(a)=0$. By the definition of $g$, we also know that $g(0)=0$.

Given a function $g$ with $g(0)=g(a)=0$, can you prove that there exists $\xi\in (0,a)$ such that $g(\xi)=g’(\xi)$?

Comment: Thank you. Actually I tried going along this line but this is exactly where I got stuck. How to interpret the condition $g=g'$ at a certain point?

Comment: $$g'(\xi) - g(\xi) = e^{\xi} \dfrac{d}{d\xi} (e^{-\xi} g(\xi))$$ should help.